# Replacing Sheet and losing Range References

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook called “Products” with 2 sheets. Sheet 1 (“Globals”) consists of many ranges that Sheet 2 refers to. I have another “master” workbook that contains a (“Globals”) sheet with all the same ranges as the “Products” workbook.

The “Master” workbook is where all the values of the ranges will be modified then saved. The (“Globals”) sheet is then deleted from the “Products” workbook and then I import the (“Globals”) sheet from the “Master” workbook.

The problem is all the cells from Sheet 2 lose the ranges they are referring to, even though I am importing a sheet with the same name and it contains the exact same range names.

Is there something I can add to my code to resolve this issue?

```
Sub ImportGlobalSheets()

Dim GlobalsFile As String
Dim GlobalsFolder As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   GlobalsFolder = Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\") - 1) & "\Globals\"
   GlobalsFile = GlobalsFolder & "Master Globals.xlsx"
   
    Workbooks.Open (GlobalsFile)
        Sheets.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Workbooks("Master Globals").Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea:
I think you should do copying the product sheet before deleting the Global sheet. (Otherwise you loose the references.) After copying the sheet it should become the active sheet. (It has references to the other workbook.) You can delete the part of the references to the other workbook replacing it (Workbook name with extension) with nothing (emplty string).

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Replace _
      What:="[NameOfYourOldWorkbook.xlsm]", Replacement:="", _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```

Then you can delete the sheet you want.  I hope it will work for you.